# Bootstrap popper won't function for the life of me

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I need to add popover/tooltip functionality to my page and I can't get it to work. I don't get any console errors, the popup just does not show up. I've tried reordering my scripts and putting them every part of my code. I tried basically every form of the activation script I could find as you will see here. Any ideas?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="au theme template">
    <meta name="author" content="Hau Nguyen">
    <meta name="keywords" content="au theme template">

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>Company</title>

    <!-- New Tab Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon_tranparent.png">


    <script src="/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#generatedTable").load("<%= table %>");
    });
    </script>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
      $('#popover').popover({
        container: 'body'
      })
    })
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
      $('.popover').popover({
        container: 'body'
      })
      $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
        trigger: 'focus'
      })
    })
    </script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })

    </script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    </script>

    <p id="noSpaceName" hidden><%= noSpaceName %><p>
    <p id="CSV" hidden><%= CSV %><p>

    <script>

      function dynamic_file() {
        var folder = document.getElementById("noSpaceName").innerHTML
        var file = document.getElementById("CSV").innerHTML
        console.log("data/" + folder + "/" + file)
        return "data/" + folder + "/" + file;
      }

      function download_file(name) {

          var dlink = document.createElement('a');
          var currentTime = new Date();
          dlink.download = document.getElementById("noSpaceName").innerHTML.concat("-" + currentTime.toDateString().split(' ').join('-'));
          dlink.href = name;
          dlink.onclick = function(e) {
              // revokeObjectURL needs a delay to work properly
              var that = this;
              setTimeout(function() {
                  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(that.href);
              }, 1500);
          };

          dlink.click();
          dlink.remove();
      }
      </script>



    <!-- Fontfaces CSS-->
    <link href="/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/font-awesome-5/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="/animsition/animsition.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/wow/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />

    <script src="/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body class="animsition">
    <div class="page-wrapper">

        <!-- MENU SIDEBAR-->
        <aside class="menu-sidebar d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="temp_logo.png" alt="Company Name" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-sidebar__content js-scrollbar1">
                <nav class="navbar-sidebar">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled navbar__list">
                        <li>
                            <a class="js-arrow" href="/">
                                <i class="fas fa-table"></i>Arrest Records</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/analytics">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i>Analytics
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- END MENU SIDEBAR-->

        <!-- PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="page-container">
            <!-- HEADER DESKTOP-->
            <header class="header-desktop">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="header-wrap">
                            <div></div>
                            <div class="custom_title">
                                <h2><font color="#666666"><%= fullName %></font></h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-box">
                                <!-- <a id="csv" href="" download=""> -->
                                <a id="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover">Popover</a>
                                    <button onclick='download_file(dynamic_file())' class="btn btn-download"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
                                    <script>  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()</script>
                                <!-- </a> -->
                                <!-- Log Out User -->
                                <form class="form-header" action="/logout?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lightish"><i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i> &nbsp; Log Out</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- END HEADER DESKTOP-->

            <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="table-responsive table--no-card m-b-30">
                                    <div id="generatedTable"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="copyright">
                                    <p>Copyright © 2020 Company. All rights reserved.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <!-- <script src="/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
    <!-- <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Vendor JS       -->
    <script src="/slick/slick.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
    <script src="/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/select2/select2.min.js">
    </script>

    <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src="/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
<!-- end document-->
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have checked your console network tab, is `popper.min.js` loading ?

Comment: @sanojlawrence I double checked and it is loading. Do you have any thoughts on that? I am getting a console warning "DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE"